# Can I have set the time for Launch image(app Start up)..? I mean,for 5 seconds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have added launch image in my application in info.plist. So,may I know is it possible to set the time for launching application for 5 seconds.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely do that, but you shouldn't. The user will be staring at an useless splash screen just for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In your app delegate's didFinishLaunching method, do:

```
sleep(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your App delegate class, in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
```

This will make your app waiting for 5 sec.

Comment: why -1?? pls give the reason too

Comment: The method name is `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, I edited that.

Comment: people could edit that-it was just a spelling mistake.instead of voting down they can correct it. thanks @MisterJack for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can set time for launch image. Below is code. It may help you.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(onLaunchExpire) userInfo:nil  repeats:NO];
```

Use this and let me know for more details..